# Roslyn Explicit IInstanceReferenceExpression Kind instead of This

Tags: c#, roslyn

When I'm getting IInstanceReferenceExpression operation for `type Instance() => this;` instance kind is `Explicit`, but I expect that kind would be `This`. Am I missing something or this is a bug in Roslyn?

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Semantics;
using System;
using System.Linq;

internal static class so39495857
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
class c
{
    c Instance() => this;
    static void Main() {}
}
");
        var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(null, new[] { tree }, new[] { mscorlib });
        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
        var node = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ArrowExpressionClauseSyntax>().First();
        var operation = model.GetOperation(node);
        var block = (IBlockStatement)operation;
        var @return = (IReturnStatement)block.Statements.First();
        var @this = (IInstanceReferenceExpression)@return.ReturnedValue;
        Console.WriteLine(@this.InstanceReferenceKind);
    }
}
```

Project on github - https://github.com/isanych/so-39495857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `Explicit` means.

[`ThisClass` is only for VB's `MyClass` keyword](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/IExpression.cs,0af208de0bdfde34,references).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Resharper and see decompiled code by default - but there are no comments there, so I missed that - will be looking and sources in such cases in future :)